# $a+b+c=?$ by having $a^2+160=b^2+5$ and $a^2+320=c^2+5$

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

My question:
$a+b+c=?$ by having $a^2+160=b^2+5$ and $a^2+320=c^2+5$.

My work so far:

$a^2+160=b^2+5\Rightarrow (b-a)(a+b)=155=31\times 5$
$a^2+320=c^2+5\Rightarrow (c-a)(c+a)=315=5\times3^2\times 7$

And now, I'm stuck.

($a,b,c$ are a members of $\mathbb Z$ and are positive)

Comment: btw, it is not linear algebra, and I bet $a,b,c$ must be integers, isn't it?

Comment: what Kind of numbers are $a,b,c$?

Comment: What is it then?(I didn't find anything more related)

Comment: $a=-13,b=-18,c=-22$ fulfills your system

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, $a,b,c>0$ hence $a=13, b=18$ and $c=\cdots$

Comment: @Abbas For starters, you have natural numbers variables and a system of equations

Comment: Thank you guys. I have my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that: $$ (b-a)(a+b)=31\times 5=155$$ as both $31$ and $5$ are prime numbers we can say either $b-a=5, a+b=31$ OR $b-a=1, a+b=155$. (becasue $a+b>b-a$)

- $b-a=5, a+b=31$, thus: $$a=13 , b=18$$
  On the other hand, we have:
  $$a^2+320=c^2+5$$
  $$\to c^2=13^2+320-5 \to c=22$$
- $b-a=1, a+b=155$, thus: $$a=77 , b=78$$
  On the other hand, we have:
  $$a^2+320=c^2+5$$
  $$\to c^2=77^2+320-5 \to c\approx 79.02 \not\in \Bbb Z$$

> Hence the only correct answer is $a=13$ and $b=18$.

Comment: You can have $a+b=155$ and $b-a=1$

Comment: دستت  درد نکنه مهرزاد.

Comment: @asdf But then we had trouble with the second equation to be an integer. I completed my answer, thank you pal.

Comment: @Abbas You are most welcome Abbas jan. :D

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

So,  $a+b> a-b$ and $a+b=\dfrac{31\cdot5}{a-b}$

Either $a+b=155, a-b=?$  or $a+b=31,a-b=?$

Check which values of $a$ keep $c$ integer

Comment: So which one would be correct?

Comment: @Abbas, Have you followed the steps in the post?

Comment: For a moment I forgot about that a,b and c are intergers!

Comment: And they are positive.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$(b+a)(b-a)=31\times 5$$

Since $a,b$ are integers, and $5,31$ are prime numbers, what is the value of $(b+a)$ and $(b-a)$?

Comment: Thank you! I have my answer.